# How can I identify samples failing minfi quality check (getQC() function)?

Tags: r, data-analysis

I'm using the minfi pipeline to analyze DNA methylation data from the EPIC array (v1). I recently had to switch from ewastools to minfi, and I'm still getting used to the way the package works.

Unfortunately, I do not have example data to reproduce, but I can share the code I'm using.

```
#' Load data
#' Import sample sheet info
targets <- read.metharray.sheet(baseDir)

#' importing idat files, result is a RGChannelSet
#rgset = read.metharray(basenames=cmv_idats)
rgset <- read.metharray.exp(targets = targets)


#' Preprocess data
#' `preprocessRaw` computes beta-value based on raw flourescence intensities
#' 
#rowMethylSet <- preprocessRaw(rgset)
methylset = preprocessRaw(rgset)
methylset

#' Create a flag for samples that we want to exclude from the final dataset
targets <- targets %>%
  mutate(exclude=FALSE)
#' Want to use all the samples.
#' Set default to FALSE.


#' Estimate sample-specific QC for methylation data
qc <- getQC(methylset)

plotQC(qc)
```

Using `getQC()` on my MethylSet object and `plotQC()`, on my qc output, I see about 5 samples that should be marked for exclusion. See image below.

[image: QC plot of DNA methylation array]

However, I do not know how to mark these samples for exclusion in the MethylSet object nor the phenotype data.

Is anyone with familiar minfi able to walk me through the process of excluding samples from downstream analysis?

I'd be grateful for your guidance. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ways you can identify and exclude low quality samples from your MethylSet object in minfi:

1. Use the sample QC plot to visually identify outliers. As you've done, use `plotQC()` on the QC object returned by `getQC()`. Note the sample names of any clear outliers.
2. Access the numeric QC metrics from `qc` and filter for outliers:

```py
low_quality <- qc$sample$DetectionPval > 0.05
exclude_samples <- names(low_quality)[low_quality]
```

3. Update your sample sheet (targets) to mark samples for exclusion:

```py
targets$exclude[targets$Sample_Name %in% exclude_samples] <- TRUE
```

4. Subset the MethylSet, retaining only samples where exclude=FALSE:

```py
methylset <- methylset[, !targets$exclude]
```

5. Optionally, overwrite the original MethylSet object to permanently remove low quality samples:

```py
methylset <- methylset[, !targets$exclude]
```

So in summary, use the QC metrics and plot to identify problematic samples, update your sample sheet to mark them for exclusion, then subset the MethylSet to retain only good quality samples for downstream analysis. Let me know if any part needs more explanation!